# LinearLayout "center_vertical"

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to put a textview in the middle of an ListView item.

So I created a LinearLayout which handle the circle and the textview in it.

**The circle is a shape:**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/accentColor"></solid>
</shape>
```

I want the TextView to be centered vertical:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vplan_list_item_hour"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

It looks right in the design tab of android studio:

[image]

but when I run the app it looks like this:

[image]

Is there anybody how know a solution for that?

Comment: strange...it looks right on my device

Comment: It's an emulator: genymotion 4.4 maybe this is the problem?

Comment: i have no idea...do you have a device to check this?

Comment: Nope, it looks identically on my android device

Comment: is it background image in `textview` or is it `shape`?

Comment: Not sure, but you can try to remove attr `android:orientation="vertical"` from `RelativeLayout` and put it into `LinearLayout`. Maybe it affects somehow.

Comment: Do you have same layout file with same content inside all drawable folders.

Answer (score 0):

use shape for background

**shape_rounded.xml** in drawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle" >

  <corners android:radius="24dp"/>

  <solid android:color="#A5A5A5" />

</shape>
```

**layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="72dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vplan_list_item_hour"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_rounded"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="1"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: and if I delete the Linearlayout, I cannot center it vertically, because when I edit the height to "match_parent" it isn't a circle anymore

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do it with `RelativeLayout`?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vplan_list_item_hour"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        ...

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify your layout a bit. I tested it in Genymotion (including Android 4.4) - works like a charm. Give it a try.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vplan_list_item_hour"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_rounded"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope, it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="72dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vplan_list_item_hour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:padding = "7dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try both : `android:gravity="center"` and `android:layout_gravity="center"` in your textview.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vplan_list_item_hour"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:padding = "7dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="1"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
```

Or you can set background for LinearLayout and check position of textview again.